# Concurrent FIFO in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, template, queue

I have implemented a simple FIFO that can optionally be used by either a single thread or way to pass data between threads.  The class is templated with arguments for the types the queue will contain and also the number of elements in the queue (queue data is stored in an `std::array`). For single thread use, it is instantiated by:

```
ST_FIFO<T, BUFFER_SIZE>
```

and for use in a multithreaded context:

```
MT_FIFO<T, BUFFER_SIZE>
```

It has these methods:

- `push` (with and without move semantics): put one item one the buffer.  Always succeeds--if buffer is full, oldest element is popped.
- `try_push`: put one item into the buffer.  If buffer is full, push fails.
- `multi_push`: push a number of items onto buffer.  Mostly useful for multi-threaded, where all items are pushed under same lock.  Always succeeds.
- `try_multi_push`: same as multi_push, but fails if buffer is full.
- `pop`: pops one item off buffer.  In single threaded version, returns immediately if buffer is empty. In multi-threaded version, this method blocks (using a condition variable) until data becomes available.
- `multi_pop`: pops a given number of items out of the buffer.  If buffer contains fewer items than number requested, returns all items in buffer.  In multi-threaded version, blocks until one item becomes available. Returns number of items popped from buffer.
- `peek`: get an item from buffer without removing it.  Can be any item in the buffer, but must be less than the number of items in the buffer.
- `size`: returns number of items in buffer.
- `is_empty`: returns true if buffer is empty.

Specifically for the multi-threaded version:

- `try_pop`: pops an item from buffer.  If buffer is empty returns false immediately.
- `wait_off`: if a thread is waiting for an item to be popped, this method can be called from another thread to terminate the waiting (useful to unblock the thread when exiting.
- `wait_on`: turns waiting back on.

After making it I found [this article](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) and [this article](https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/), which implement concurrent queue's in a very similar manner.  I think what I have is pretty good.  Any comments?  Should I release the locks before notifying the condition variables? (if I do, helgrind complains that locks aren't held, but is that a big deal?)  There is one thing I'd like to figure out if possible.  With the way to locks are set up now, it's not possible to push and pop from the buffer simultaneously.  Having one lock for the input and one for the output would be problematic when the queue is empty or has one element. Any thoughts on that?

**fifo.h**

```
#ifndef FIFO_H
#define FIFO_H

#include <array>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include <type_traits>

//compiler I have is not c++14 compliant
template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B,T>::type;

template<class T, std::size_t CAPACITY, bool THREADSAFE = true>
class FIFO_t
{
public:
    FIFO_t(): buf_capacity_(CAPACITY + 1), // add dummy unused element so we can tell the difference between when buffer is full and when it is empty.
        input_index_(0), output_index_(0), wait_flag_(true) { }

    // copy constructor needs to be fancy because the mutex is not copyable or
    // movable.  Uses private helper functions to pick single or
    // multi-threaded version

    FIFO_t(const FIFO_t &that):buf_capacity_(CAPACITY + 1)
    {
        copy_fifo(that, std::integral_constant<bool, THREADSAFE>{});
    }

    FIFO_t& operator=(const FIFO_t& that)
    {
        return copy_fifo(that, std::integral_constant<bool, THREADSAFE>{});
    }

//Single thread public definitions*********************************************

    //push --pop oldest element if queue is full
    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, bool>
    push(const T &data)
    {
        return push_(data);
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, bool>
    push(T &&data)
    {
        return push_(std::move(data));
    }

    // push and fail if queue is full
    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, bool>
    try_push(const T &data)
    {
        return try_push_(data);
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, bool>
    multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            push_(data[i]);
        }
        return true;
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, size_t>
    try_multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
    {
        size_t num_pushed = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count && get_size() < capacity() ; ++i)
        {
            try_push_(data[i]);
            num_pushed++;
        }

        return num_pushed;
    }

    // no need for pop_nowait, wait_on or wait_off functions in
    // single threaded version

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, bool>
    pop(T &data)
    {
        return pop_(data);
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, size_t>
    multi_pop(T data[], size_t count)
    {
        size_t num_popped = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count && !is_empty_(); ++i)
        {
            pop_(data[i]);
            num_popped++;
        }
        return num_popped;
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, bool>
    peek(std::size_t ind, T &data) const
    {
        std::size_t buf_size = get_size();
        if (ind >= buf_size)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            data = buffer_data_[(output_index_ + ind) % buf_capacity_];
            return true;
        }
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, std::size_t>
    size() const
    {
        return get_size();
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<not trigger, bool>
    is_empty() const
    {
       return is_empty_();
    }

//mutlithreaded public definitions

    //push --pop oldest element if queue is full
    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, bool>
    push(const T &data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
        bool result = push_(data);
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
        return result;
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, bool>
    push(T &&data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
        bool result = push_(std::move(data));
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
        return result;
    }

    // push and fail if queue is full
    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, bool>
    try_push(const T &data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
            this_lock.lock();
        bool result = try_push_(data);
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
        return result;
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, bool>
    multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            push_(data[i]);
        }
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();

        return true;
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, size_t>
    try_multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);

        size_t num_pushed = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count && get_size() < capacity() ; ++i)
        {
            try_push_(data[i]);
            num_pushed++;
        }
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();

        return num_pushed;
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, bool>
    pop(T &data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
        cv_.wait(this_lock, [this]{return !(is_empty_() && wait_flag_);});
        return pop_(data);
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, bool>
    try_pop(T &data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex_);
        return pop_(data);
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, size_t>
    multi_pop(T data[], size_t count)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
        cv_.wait(this_lock, [this]{return !(is_empty_() && wait_flag_);});

        size_t num_popped = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count && !is_empty_(); ++i)
        {
            pop_(data[i]);
            num_popped++;
        }
        return num_popped;
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, bool>
    peek(std::size_t ind, T &data) const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
        std::size_t buf_size = get_size();

        if (ind >= buf_size)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            data = buffer_data_[(output_index_ + ind) % buf_capacity_];
            return true;
        }
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, size_t>
    size() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
        return get_size();
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger, bool>
    is_empty() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
        return is_empty_();
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger>
    wait_on()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
        wait_flag_ = true;
    }

    template<bool trigger = THREADSAFE>
    enable_if_t<trigger>
    wait_off()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
            wait_flag_ = false;
        //this_lock.unlock();
            cv_.notify_all();
        }

    //same for single and multi-threaded versions
    std::size_t capacity() const
    {
        return  CAPACITY;
    }

private:
    std::array<T, CAPACITY+1> buffer_data_;
    const std::size_t buf_capacity_;
    std::size_t input_index_;
    std::size_t output_index_;
    std::atomic_bool wait_flag_;
    mutable std::mutex mutex_;
    mutable std::condition_variable cv_;


    FIFO_t& copy_fifo(const FIFO_t& that, std::true_type)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_, std::defer_lock);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> that_lock(that.mutex_, std::defer_lock);
        std::lock(this_lock, that_lock);

        buffer_data_ = that.buffer_data_;
        input_index_ = that.input_index_;
        output_index_ = that.output_index_;
        wait_flag_    = that.wait_flag_.load();
        return *this;
    }

    FIFO_t& copy_fifo(const FIFO_t& that, std::false_type)
    {
        buffer_data_ = that.buffer_data_;
        input_index_ = that.input_index_;
        output_index_ = that.output_index_;
        wait_flag_    = that.wait_flag_.load();
        return *this;
    }

    // non thread safe version for internal use (assumes calling function
    // will acquire the lock)
    std::size_t get_size() const
    {
        if (input_index_ == output_index_)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (input_index_ > output_index_)
        {
            return input_index_ - output_index_;
        }
        else
        {
            return input_index_ + buf_capacity_ - output_index_;
        }
    }

    bool is_empty_() const
    {
        return (input_index_ == output_index_);
    }

    bool push_(const T &data)
    {
        if(get_size() == CAPACITY)
        {
            T temp;
            pop_(temp);
        }

        buffer_data_[input_index_] = data;
        input_index_ = (input_index_ + 1) % buf_capacity_;
        return true;
    }

    bool push_(T &&data)
    {
        if (get_size() == CAPACITY)
        {
            T temp;
            pop_(temp);
        }

        buffer_data_[input_index_] = std::move(data);
        input_index_ = (input_index_ + 1) % buf_capacity_;
        return true;
    }

    bool try_push_(const T &data)
    {
        if (get_size() == CAPACITY)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer_data_[input_index_] = data;
            input_index_ = (input_index_ + 1) % buf_capacity_;
            return true;
        }
    }

    bool pop_(T &data)
    {
        if (is_empty_())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            data = std::move(buffer_data_[output_index_]);
            output_index_ = (output_index_ + 1) % buf_capacity_;
            return true;
        }
    }
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
using ST_FIFO = FIFO_t<T, N, false>; //alias for a single threaded fifo

template<class T, std::size_t N> //alias for a multi-threaded fifo
using MT_FIFO = FIFO_t<T, N, true>;

#endif // FIFO_H
```

Test driver (not complete):

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "fifo.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <map>

bool TEST_Initially_Empty()
{
    ST_FIFO<int, 10> buf;

    if (buf.size() == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool TEST_Put_Get_FIFO()
{
    const int num_elements = 5;
    int a[num_elements], b[num_elements];
    ST_FIFO<int, 10> buf;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = std::rand() % 1000;
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        if (!buf.push(a[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        if (!buf.pop(b[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool TEST_Put_to_full()
{
    std::size_t cnt = 10;

    ST_FIFO<int, 10> buf;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        if (!buf.push(i))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (buf.try_push(cnt))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool TEST_Put_to_full_DiscardOldest()
{
    std::size_t cnt = 10;

    ST_FIFO<int, 10> buf;
    int a[10], temp, temp2;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        if (!buf.push(i))
        {
            std::cout << "returning false" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    buf.push(cnt);
    buf.peek(0,temp);
    buf.peek(9,temp2);
    if (temp != 1 || temp2 != 10)
    {
        return false;
    }

    buf.pop(temp);
    if (a[1] != temp)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool TEST_Put_to_full_DiscardNewest()
{
    std::size_t cnt = 10;

    ST_FIFO<int, 10> buf;
    int a[10], temp;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        if (!buf.try_push(i))
        {
            std::cout << "returning false" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (buf.try_push(cnt))
    {
        return false;
    }
    buf.pop(temp);
    if (a[0] != temp)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool TEST_multi_push()
{
    std::size_t cnt = 10;

    ST_FIFO<int, 10> buf;
    int a[10], temp;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    buf.multi_push(a, 10);

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        buf.peek(i,temp);
        if (temp !=a[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool TEST_multi_push_overflow()
{
    std::size_t cnt = 10;

    ST_FIFO<int, 7> buf;
    int a[cnt], temp;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    buf.multi_push(a, cnt);

    for (int i=0; i<7; ++i)
    {
        buf.peek(i,temp);
        if (temp !=a[i+3])
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool TEST_try_multi_push()
{
    std::size_t cnt = 10;

    ST_FIFO<int, 10> buf;
    int a[cnt], temp;

    buf.push(234);
    buf.push(249);
    buf.push(233);
    buf.pop(temp);
    buf.pop(temp);
    buf.pop(temp);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    buf.try_multi_push(a, cnt);

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        buf.peek(i,temp);
        if (temp !=a[i])
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool TEST_try_multi_push_overflow()
{
    std::size_t cnt = 10;

    ST_FIFO<int, 7> buf;
    int a[cnt], temp;

    buf.push(234);
    buf.push(249);
    buf.push(233);
    buf.pop(temp);
    buf.pop(temp);
    buf.pop(temp);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    buf.try_multi_push(a, cnt);

    for (int i=0; i<7; ++i)
    {
        buf.peek(i,temp);
        if (temp !=a[i])
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool TEST_multi_pop()
{
    std::size_t cnt = 10;

    ST_FIFO<int, 10> buf;
    int a[cnt], b[cnt], temp;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    buf.push(28);
    buf.push(240);
    buf.try_multi_push(a, cnt);

    buf.pop(temp);
    if (temp != 28)
    {
        return false;
    }
    buf.pop(temp);

    if (temp != 240)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int count = buf.multi_pop(b,10);
    if (count != 8)
    {
        std::cout << "count = " << count << ", expected value 8." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {

        if (b[i] !=a[i])
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void emptyTest(MT_FIFO<int, 100> &buf, const std::size_t num_elements)
{
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 5; ++ctr)
    {
        std::cout << "waiting..." << ctr << std::endl;
        usleep(1000000);
    }


    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        buf.push(std::rand() % 1000);
    }
}

bool TEST_Get_From_Empty()
{
    MT_FIFO<int,100> buf;
    const std::size_t num_elements = 5;
    int a[num_elements];

    std::thread t1(emptyTest, std::ref(buf), num_elements);

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start =
            std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    if(buf.pop(a[0]))
    {
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point stop =
                std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        double diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>> (stop-start).count();
        if (diff < 4)
        {
            std::cout << "diff = " << diff << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }

    t1.join();

    return true;
}

bool TEST_peek()
{
    const std::size_t num_elements = 100;
    ST_FIFO<int,100> buf;
    int a[num_elements];
    int b[num_elements];

    if (buf.peek(0,a[0]))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //condition buffer so next time we fill it, the counters will transition
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < num_elements/2; ++i)
    {
        if (! buf.push(rand() % 1000))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (! buf.pop(a[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (! buf.is_empty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 1000;
        if(!buf.push(a[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!buf.peek(i,b[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (a[i] != b[i])
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    if (buf.peek(num_elements,b[0]))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool TEST_Wrap_around()
{
    const int num_elements = 100;
    int a[num_elements], b[num_elements];
    bool test_result = true;
    ST_FIFO<int,10> buf;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements - 1; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = std::rand() % 1000;
        a[i + 1] = std::rand() % 1000;

        if (!buf.push(a[i]))
        {
            test_result = false;
        }

        if (!buf.push(a[i+1]))
        {
            test_result =  false;
        }

        if (!buf.pop(b[i]))
        {
            test_result = false;
        }
        if (!buf.pop(b[i+1]))
        {
            test_result = false;
        }

        if (a[i] != b[i] || a[i + 1] != b[i + 1])
        {
            test_result = false;
        }
    }

    return test_result;
}

bool TEST_size()
{
    ST_FIFO<unsigned char, 15> buf;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < buf.capacity(); ++i)
    {
        if (buf.size() != i)
        {
            std::cout << "size fail buf_size = " << buf.size() << ", i = " << i << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (! buf.push(rand() % 255))
        {
            std::cout << "push fail i = " << i << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (buf.size() != i+1)
        {
            std::cout << "size fail buf_size = " << buf.size() << ", i = " << i << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool TEST_capacity()
{
    std::size_t num_elements = 15;
    ST_FIFO<unsigned char, 15> buf;

    if (buf.capacity() != num_elements)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool TEST_st_copy()
{
    const int num_elements = 5;
    int a[num_elements], b[num_elements];
    ST_FIFO<int, 10> buf;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = std::rand() % 1000;
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        if (!buf.push(a[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    ST_FIFO<int,10> buf2(buf);


    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        buf2.pop(b[i]);
        if (b[i] != a[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


bool TEST_mt_copy()
{
    const int num_elements = 5;
    int a[num_elements], b[num_elements];
    MT_FIFO<int, 10> buf;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = std::rand() % 1000;
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        if (!buf.push(a[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    MT_FIFO<int,10> buf2(buf);


    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        buf2.pop(b[i]);
        if (b[i] != a[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template<class T>
struct ts_obj
{
    ts_obj() {}
    ts_obj(T obj):obj_(obj) {}

    T operator()()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        return obj_;
    }

     void operator=(const T &obj)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        obj_ = obj;
    }


private:
    T obj_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
};


void worker_thread(MT_FIFO<std::packaged_task<int()>,10> &fifo, ts_obj<bool> &flag)
{
    while(flag())
    {
        std::packaged_task<int()> task{};
        if (fifo.pop(task))
        {
            task();
        }
        else
        {
            //std::cout << "didn't execute task..." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

bool TEST_MT()
{
    ts_obj<bool> flag(true);
    MT_FIFO<std::packaged_task<int()>, 10> fifo;

    std::thread thread1(&worker_thread, std::ref(fifo), std::ref(flag));
    std::packaged_task<int()> task1([]{return 1;});

    auto result = task1.get_future();

    fifo.push(std::move(task1));


    sleep(1);
    //std::cout << "Result is " << result.get() << std::endl;
    flag = false;
    fifo.wait_off();

    thread1.join();
    return true;
}

enum class task_status{
    INVALID = -1,
    NOT_STARTED = 0,
    IN_PROGRESS,
    INTERRUPTED,
    FAILED,
    SUCCESS
};

const static std::map<task_status, std::string> enum_str {
    {task_status::INVALID, "INVALID"},
    {task_status::NOT_STARTED, "NOT_STARTED"},
    {task_status::IN_PROGRESS, "IN_PROGRESS"},
    {task_status::INTERRUPTED, "INTERRUPTED"},
    {task_status::FAILED, "FAILED"},
    {task_status::SUCCESS, "SUCCESS"}
};

class baseTask
{
public:
    baseTask(): m_status(task_status::INVALID) {}
    virtual ~baseTask () {}
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    virtual void cancel() = 0;
    task_status status() {return m_status();}
protected:
    //std::atomic<task_status> m_status;
    ts_obj<task_status> m_status;
private:

};

class derivedtask : public baseTask
{
public:
    derivedtask() {}
    derivedtask(int wait):wait_time(wait), flag(false) {m_status = task_status::NOT_STARTED;}
    ~derivedtask() {}
    void execute()
    {
        m_status = task_status::IN_PROGRESS;
        int ctr = 0;
        while (ctr < wait_time && !flag())
        {
            //std::cout << "waiting " << ctr << std::endl;
            sleep(1);
            ctr++;
        }

        if (flag())
        {
            m_status = task_status::INTERRUPTED;
        }
        else
        {
            m_status = task_status::SUCCESS;
        }

    }

    void cancel()
    {
        flag = true;
    }

private:
    int wait_time = 0;
    ts_obj<bool> flag;
};

void worker_thread2(MT_FIFO<std::shared_ptr<baseTask>, 10> &fifo, ts_obj<bool> &flag)
{
    while(flag())
    {
        std::shared_ptr<baseTask> task{};
        if (fifo.pop(task))
        {
            task->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            //std::cout << "didn't execute task..." << std::endl;
        }

    }
}

bool TEST_MT2()
{
    ts_obj<bool> flag(true);
    MT_FIFO<std::shared_ptr<baseTask>, 10> fifo;

    std::thread thread1(&worker_thread2, std::ref(fifo), std::ref(flag));
    //std::packaged_task<int()> task1([]{return 1;});
    std::shared_ptr<baseTask> task1(new derivedtask(5));
    std::shared_ptr<baseTask> task2(new derivedtask(5));
    //auto result = task1.get_future();

    fifo.push(task1);
    fifo.push(task2);
    int ctr = 0;
    while (task1->status() == task_status::NOT_STARTED ||
           task1->status() == task_status::IN_PROGRESS)
    {
        ctr++;
        //std::cout <<"waiting for task 1 to complete" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
        if (ctr == 3)
        {
            task1->cancel();
        }
    }
    while (task2->status() == task_status::NOT_STARTED ||
           task2->status() == task_status::IN_PROGRESS)
    {
        //std::cout <<"waiting for task 2 to complete" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
    //std::cout << "Result is " << enum_str.at(task1->status()) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Result is " << enum_str.at(task2->status()) << std::endl;

    task1.reset();
    task2.reset();

    flag = false;
    fifo.wait_off();

    thread1.join();
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "TEST Initially empty: " << (TEST_Initially_Empty() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Get Put: " << (TEST_Put_Get_FIFO() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Wrap Around: " << (TEST_Wrap_around() ? "PASS" : "FAIL")<< std::endl  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Put_to_full: " << (TEST_Put_to_full() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Put_to_full, discarding oldest: " << (TEST_Put_to_full_DiscardOldest() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Put_to_full, discarding newest: " << (TEST_Put_to_full_DiscardNewest() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Multi-push: " << (TEST_multi_push() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Multi-push-overflow: " << (TEST_multi_push_overflow() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Try-Multi-push: " << (TEST_try_multi_push() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Try-Multi-push-overflow: " << (TEST_try_multi_push_overflow() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Try-multi-pop-overflow: " << (TEST_multi_pop() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Get_from_empty: " << (TEST_Get_From_Empty() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Peek: " << (TEST_peek() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Size: " << (TEST_size() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST Capacity: " << (TEST_capacity() ? "PASS" : "FAIL")  << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST ST Copy: " << (TEST_st_copy() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST MT Copy: " << (TEST_mt_copy() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST MT: " << (TEST_MT() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST MT2: " << (TEST_MT2() ? "PASS" : "FAIL") << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Based on the feedback given, I split it into two classes. With the goal of tinkering and learning this also seemed like a good use case for the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, so I used it in my revised classes. I also made a few minor tweaks such replacing mutable reference arguments with pointers on the pop and peek functions.  Here it is:

```
#ifndef FIFO_H
#define FIFO_H

#include <array>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

// A FIFO class.  Implements a statically allocated FIFO.  Two versions
// are defined--a single threaded version and a threadsafe version.
// uses CRTP for experimentation.
template<class T, size_t CAPACITY, class DERIVED>
class FIFO_BASE_t
{
public:
    bool push(const T &data) {return derived_type().derived_push(data);}

    bool push(T &&data){return derived_type().derived_push(std::move(data));}

    bool try_push(const T &data){return derived_type().derived_try_push(data);}

    bool multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
        {return derived_type().derived_multi_push(data, count);}

    size_t try_multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
        {return derived_type().derived_try_multi_push(data, count);}

    bool pop(T *data) {return derived_type().derived_pop(data);}

    size_t multi_pop(T data[], size_t count)
        {return derived_type().derived_multi_pop(data, count);}

    bool peek(size_t index, T *data) const
        {return derived_const().derived_peek(index, data);}

    size_t size() const {return derived_const().derived_size();}

    bool is_empty() const {return derived_const().derived_is_empty();}

protected:
    FIFO_BASE_t() {}
    DERIVED& copy_fifo(const DERIVED& rhs)
    {
        buffer_data_  = rhs.buffer_data_;
        input_index_  = rhs.input_index_;
        output_index_ = rhs.output_index_;
        return derived_type();
    }

    size_t size_() const
    {
        if (input_index_ == output_index_)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (input_index_ > output_index_)
        {
            return input_index_ - output_index_;
        }

        return input_index_ + CAPACITY + 1 - output_index_;
    }

    bool is_empty_() const
    {
        return input_index_ == output_index_;
    }

    bool push_one_(const T &data)
    {
        if(size_() == CAPACITY)
        {
            T temp;
            pop_one_(&temp);
        }

        buffer_data_[input_index_] = data;
        input_index_ = (input_index_ + 1) % (CAPACITY + 1);
        return true;
    }

    bool push_one_(T &&data)
    {
        if (size_() == CAPACITY)
        {
            T temp;
            pop_one_(&temp);
        }

        buffer_data_[input_index_] = std::move(data);
        input_index_ = (input_index_ + 1) % (CAPACITY + 1);
        return true;
    }

    bool try_push_one_(const T &data)
    {
        if (size_() < CAPACITY)
        {
            buffer_data_[input_index_] = data;
            input_index_ = (input_index_ + 1) % (CAPACITY + 1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool multi_push_(const T data[], size_t count)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            push_one_(data[i]);
        }
        return true;
    }

    size_t try_multi_push_(const T data[], size_t count)
    {
        size_t num_pushed = 0;
        while(num_pushed < count)
        {
            if(!try_push_one_(data[num_pushed]))
            {
                break;
            }
            num_pushed++;
        }
        return num_pushed;
    }

    bool pop_one_(T *data)
    {
        if (is_empty_())
        {
            return false;
        }
        *data = std::move(buffer_data_[output_index_]);
        output_index_ = (output_index_ + 1) % (CAPACITY + 1);
        return true;
    }

    size_t multi_pop_(T data[], size_t count)
    {
        size_t num_popped = 0;
        while(num_popped < count)
        {
            if (!pop_one_(&data[num_popped]))
            {
                break;
            }
            num_popped++;
        }
        return num_popped;
    }

    bool peek_(size_t index, T *data) const
    {
        if (index < size_())
        {
            *data = buffer_data_[(output_index_ + index) % (CAPACITY + 1)];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

private:
    DERIVED& derived_type() {return static_cast<DERIVED&>(*this); }
    const DERIVED& derived_const() const
        {return static_cast<const DERIVED&>(*this);}

    std::array<T, CAPACITY + 1> buffer_data_;
    size_t input_index_ = 0;
    size_t output_index_ = 0;

};


//FIFo for single threaded operation
//T is object type the FIFO will store. CAPACITY is the number of items the
// FIFO can concurrently store.
template<class T, size_t CAPACITY>
class ST_FIFO: public FIFO_BASE_t<T, CAPACITY, ST_FIFO<T, CAPACITY>>
{
public:
    ST_FIFO() {}
    ST_FIFO(const ST_FIFO& rhs)
    {
        this->copy_fifo(rhs);
    }

    ST_FIFO& operator=(const ST_FIFO& rhs)
    {
        return this->copy_fifo(rhs);
    }

    friend class FIFO_BASE_t<T, CAPACITY, ST_FIFO>;
private:
    bool derived_push(const T &data) {return this->push_one_(data);}

    bool derived_push(T &&data){return this->push_one_(std::move(data));}

    bool derived_try_push(const T &data){return this->try_push_one_(data);}

    bool derived_multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
        {return this->multi_push_(data, count);}

    size_t derived_try_multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
        {return this->try_multi_push_(data, count);}

    bool derived_pop(T *data) {return this->pop_one_(data);}

    size_t derived_multi_pop(T data[], size_t count)
        {return this->multi_pop_(data, count);}

    bool derived_peek(size_t index, T *data) const {return this->peek_(index, data);}

    size_t derived_size() const {return this->size_();}

    bool derived_is_empty() const {return this->is_empty_();}
};


//threadsafe version of FIFO
//T is object type the FIFO will store. CAPACITY is the number of items the
// FIFO can concurrently store.
template<class T, size_t CAPACITY>
class MT_FIFO: public FIFO_BASE_t<T, CAPACITY, MT_FIFO<T, CAPACITY>>
{
public:
    MT_FIFO():wait_flag_(true) {}

    MT_FIFO(const MT_FIFO& rhs)
    {
        lock(mutex_, rhs.mutex_);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mutex_, std::adopt_lock);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (rhs.mutex_, std::adopt_lock);
        wait_flag_ = wait_flag_.load();
        this->copy_fifo(rhs);
    }

    MT_FIFO& operator=(const MT_FIFO& rhs)
    {
        if(this == &rhs)
        {
            return this;
        }
        lock(mutex_, rhs.mutex_);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (mutex_, std::adopt_lock);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> (rhs.mutex_, std::adopt_lock);
        wait_flag_ = wait_flag_.load();
        return this->copy_fifo(rhs);
    }

    bool try_pop(T *data)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        return this->pop_one_(data);
    }

    void wait_off() {wait_flag_ = false; cv_.notify_all();}

    void wait_on() {wait_flag_ = true;}


  friend class FIFO_BASE_t<T, CAPACITY, MT_FIFO>;
private:
    bool derived_push(const T &data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        bool result = this->push_one_(data);
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
        return result;
    }

    bool derived_push(T &&data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        bool result = this->push_one_(std::move(data));
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
        return result;
    }

    bool derived_try_push(const T &data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        bool result =  this->try_push_one_(data);
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
        return result;
    }

    bool derived_multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        bool result = multi_push_(data, count);
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
        return result;
    }

    size_t derived_try_multi_push(const T data[], size_t count)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        size_t num_pushed =  try_multi_push_(data, count);
        //this_lock.unlock();
        cv_.notify_one();
        return num_pushed;
    }

    bool derived_pop(T *data)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        cv_.wait(this_lock, [this]{return !(this->is_empty_() && wait_flag_);});
        return this->pop_one_(data);
    }

    size_t derived_multi_pop(T data[], size_t count)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        cv_.wait(this_lock, [this]{return !(this->is_empty_() && wait_flag_);});
        return multi_pop_(data, count);
    }

    bool derived_peek(size_t index, T *data) const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        return peek_(index, data);
    }

    size_t derived_size() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        return this->size_();
    }

    bool derived_is_empty() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> this_lock(mutex_);
        return this->is_empty_();
    }

    std::atomic_bool wait_flag_;
    mutable std::mutex mutex_;
    mutable std::condition_variable cv_;

};


#endif // FIFO_H
```

see it working at [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/871e74e32c35b6f1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm in a bit of a hurry so I'll only touch on the big high level stuff that I noticed.

## Abuse of SFINAE

I think that the way you are designing two different use cases into one template class and switching between them is an abuse of SFINAE.

The most obvious indication of this is the fact that you define two aliases `ST_FIFO` and `MT_FIFO` to act as if they were two separate templates.

I understand that this is a way to avoid code duplication but I do not approve of it. The added clutter and the extra overhead of a mutex and atomic variables etc on the single threaded queue is also less than ideal.

What I would do instead is to make a shared, hidden base class which holds the shared functionality. Something like this perhaps:

```
namespace detail{
    class queue_base{
    public:
        push(); // etc
    protected:
        queue_base(); // Make CTOR protected to prevent direct instantiation
    };
}
class queue : public detail::queue_base{};
class concurrent_queue : public detail::queue_base{};
```

In this way you can share the common implementation of methods between the two variants without abusing SFINAE and without the single threaded version having the size overhead of the mutex etc. One might be worried that this is a violation of the [Liskov Susbstitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) but as the base class is hidden in a "detail" namespace it's a clear hint not to use it and it cannot be directly instantiated. Yes, the user may accept a pointer or reference to a `queue_base` object but they are going through hoops to do it and one might argue that they both provide the same base contract so they are Liskov substitutable. I find it acceptable, although not ideal.  The other option is to let `queue`  and `concurrent_queue` have a member of type `detail::queue_base` and forward the method calls but I don't find this forwarding very appealing either.

Comment: both answers so far are great - I will implement and repost.

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't abuse SFINAE to provide two classes in one.
   It doesn't work for fields, and is generally clunky.

   Instead, either invest in private inheritance and judicious use of `using`, or write them separately.
2. Your  `operator=` deadlocks on self-assignment in the multithreaded case.
3. If you do an early return, there's no use to writing an else-block.

   ```
   if (boolean_expression)
   {
       some_code;
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       some_other_code;
       return false;
   }
   ```

   Better change that to:

   ```
   if (boolean_expression) {
       some_code;
       return true;
   }
   some_other_code;
   return false;
   ```
4. You can return a `bool` directly, no need to put it into a condition:

   ```
   if (boolean_expression)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
   ```

   Better change that to:

   ```
   return boolean_expression;
   ```
5. `buf_capacity_` has exactly two uses: Padding out your class-size and pessimizing code.
   It's always exactly `CAPACITY + 1`.
6. Most of your multithreaded code is of the form:

   ```
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> this_lock(this->mutex_);
   auto result = somecode();
   //this_lock.unlock();
   cv_.notify_one(); // or occassionally better cv_.notify_all();
   return result;
   ```

   Defining a simple private member-template helps clean it up:

   ```
   template<bool all = false, class F>
   auto locked(F f) noexcept(noexcept(f())) {
       auto result = (std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex_), f()); // minimal lock-duration
       all ? cv_.notify_all() : cv_.notify_one();
       return result;
   }
   // Used like:
   return locked([&]{ return somecode(); });
   ```

Posted a rewrite using my suggestions for review here: [(Optionally Concurrent) FIFO](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163400/optionally-concurrent-fifo)